# WinForms cursor hidden only on one Form

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, hide

I have a C# application with 2 simultaneous visible forms, and I need to hide mouse cursor when it is over only on one of them. If I use Cursor.Hide() it applies the change for both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a "blank" cursor, and set `myForm.Cursor = blankCursor;`  This will make that specific form show a specific cursor, which could be completely transparent.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement this logic by using the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events one each form something like:

```
    private void frm1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Cursor.Hide();
    }
    private void frm1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Cursor.Show();
    }
```

do the abobe on the form that should hide the cursor and add this to the form that should make the cursor visible:

```
    private void frm2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Cursor.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this thanks, but, the mouse pointer appear over controls inside the form

Comment: try removing the MouseLeave on frm1... but I dont know if cursor will be hidden even to other windows until it enters frm2

Comment: It seemed a good idea, but I don't know why sometimes the MouseEnter event don't run when mouse enter on the forms, so, dissapear and appear when windows want it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `this.Cursor = Cursors.None`, instead of `Cursor.Hide()`?

Comment: Cursors.None don't exist as valid cursor

Comment: This solution is (unfortunately) WPF-specific.  Apparently (though unspecified) the OP wanted WinForms solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Control.MouseEnter and Control.MouseLeave events to trigger hiding or displaying the cursor

Answer (score 0):

If you're hiding the cursor so that the user can't do anything on the form, consider using `this.UseWaitCursor = true;` instead.