# Hide cursor on my form

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help on how to hide the cursor when the mouse is over one of my application forms. I know the code is Cursor.Hide() and Cursor.Show() for the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events respectively. Applying this to the form itself doesn't work. So I inserted a panel (set its Dock property to Fill) to contain the other controls. The code worked for the panel but when I started adding controls, it didn't.
My guess is that I have to apply the code to each control. With about 25 controls on my form, that seems rather clumsy.
My idea was this (I'm sorry for the formatting; I'm typing this from a dumbphone):

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
{
    control.MouseEnter += control_MouseEnter;
    control.MouseLeave += control_MouseLeave;
}
```

The code was inside FrmScreen_Load. But it still doesn't work. Am I missing something?

I'm working in C# but solutions in VB.NET are acceptable.

Comment: What do you mean 'it still doesn't work' is the for loop not executing or is the code you are using to show and hide the cursor not working

Comment: You can also create empty cursor file using cursor editor and use it as the form Cursor property - `this.Cursor = new Cursor("path to empty cursor file here");`

Comment: @msarchet I think the problem is that in the loop, when the mouse is on a control, control_MouseEnter (which hides the cursor) is called, but momentarily before that, the mouse has just left another control which displays the cursor. In all, maybe the two events are being called simultaneously so that it seems the cursor is always shown. Just what I think

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I thought about doing that. I decided to do it as a last resort if there's not a better solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinForms cursor hidden only on one Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471982/winforms-cursor-hidden-only-on-one-form)

Comment: @LarsTech You're right. Just discovered that yesterday, too. I was typing from the mobile version so there was no suggestion dropdown. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It is suggested to use [`Cursor.Hide();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.hide.aspx) in the form constructor.

> Applying this to the form itself doesn't work

I dont think you'll ever have to care about cursor when you move out of your Application's territory.The very time the form initializes put the code there.

```
public Form1()
        {    
            InitializeComponent();
            Cursor.Hide();
        }
```

One more recommended way is to iterate through control collection i.e.

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
  c.Cursor.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm displaying two forms at once in my application. Setting ~Cursor.Hide()~ in the constructor hides the cursor on the other form, too.

Comment: what about setting cursor.show on the other form. Perhaps this.cursor.show() should work on form2.

Answer (score 0):

You said this: @msarchet I think the problem is that in the loop, when the mouse is on a control, control_MouseEnter (which hides the cursor) is called, but momentarily before that, the mouse has just left another control which displays the cursor. In all, maybe the two events are being called simultaneously so that it seems the cursor is always shown. Just what I think

If you think that is the problem, don't do a cursor.show for leaving all the controls, you only want it to show when leaving the panel. Set a cursor.show and a cursor.hide on your panel and all other controls just get a cursor.hide.

Comment: If you read the question very well, that was my first attempt. It works only when there are no controls in the panel (which is useless).

Comment: I think you need to re-read what I said. You never mentioned only putting cursor.hide on all controls and both cursor.hide and cursor.show on only the panel. You said you tried to put both on the panel and then tried to put both on all controls. I am not saying either one of those. I am saying put the cursor.hide and cursor.show events on the panel and only put cursor.hide events on the other controls.

Comment: I get you now. But from the MSDN page (sorry, I don't have the link now) on Cursor.Hide(), there is a fair warning that there should be a corresponding Cursor.Show(). I think they are right because sometimes, the cursor doesn't get hidden while at other times it does.

Comment: OK, it was just a thought. The panel's cursor.show should be able to handle it.